# Firebird user for remote connection

Tags: firebird

The Firebird DB is running on Windows machine. I can connect remotely to the database via alias and run select query on one of the tables, but only if login as SYSDBA user. But I need to do that if login as a user with limited rights.

For that I have created a Firebird user via add command of GSEC. Then I granted select rights to the table for that user via isql. If login locally as created user I can succesfully run a select query on the table. 
Unfortunately such user configuration is not sufficient to run select query from my C# app running on remote machine.
What should be changed to make it working?

Comment: What is an error message you get when trying to run your query from C# app?

Comment: what is Firebird version ? Maybe you use different auth plugins

Comment: Please provide a [mcve], and be specific about the errors received. It sounds like you either didn't create the user, or didn't give that user sufficient privileges.

Comment: Thank you guys for interest in the subject. The problem is already solved, after recreating the user account in Firebird it started working. So something went wrong when doing this the first time.